# Reading part of a remote page in PHP

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I have a page at URL **http://site.com/params.** I want to read only the **first n characters** from this remote page. Functions like `readfile()`, `file_get_contents()` and `curl` seem to download whole of the pages. Can't figure out how to do this in PHP.

Please help...!

Comment: Read about the `offset` and `maxlen` parameters of [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: @Josh, But doesn't that download the whole page and then give me the first n characters? Correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: I can't imagine that it would. It should only read up to `maxlen` characters, or all by default. I'll let someone else qualify that.

Comment: @Josh, Could you please explain and post it as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) may be what you're looking for if the `maxlen` parameter is utilized. By default, this function:

```
//Reads entire file into a string
$wholePage= file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
```

However, the **maxlen** parameter is the *maximum length of data read*.

```
// Read 14 characters starting from the 1st character
$section = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', NULL, NULL, 0, 14);
```

This implies that the entire file is not read, and only `maxlen` characters are read, if `maxlen` is defined.

Comment: @ahmedtabrez No problem. Keep in mind, this is how I understood it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do through sockets [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php)

```
$handle = fopen("http://domain.com/params", "r");
$buffer = fgets($handle, 100);
echo $buffer;
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: using fopen with url is assumed that `allow_url_fopen` in php.ini is enabled [see here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)

Comment: @yAnTar, Sorry, The code you mentioned downloads the whole page which is what I don't want to do. And could you please explain how sockets can be used here?